# How to retrieve email content body from "text/html; charset=us-ascii" with Spring Integration Mail

Tags: email, spring-integration, exchange-server, imap

I am using Spring Integration Mail to pull and process email's content from Exchange Server.
using imap-idle-channel-adapter. Email are being pulled fine.
If email has attachments, the content type is multipart/mixed ("text/html; charset=us-ascii" and attachment) and email body from text/html; charset=us-ascii is retrieved fine.

**However, if email doesn't have attachments the content type is just "text/html; charset=us-ascii". Sometimes, it comes as "text/html charset=windows-1252".
In any case, even though the content object is String, the email body is retrieved as null or empty.**

How should I retrieve the email body? If email is multipart/mixed, the email body for text/html is retrieved fine. So weird!

**Code**

[image]

**Console**

[image]

**The configuration is like this.**

```
<int-mail:imap-idle-channel-adapter id="customAdapter"
  store-uri="imaps://[username]:[password]@[exchange-imap-server]:993/INBOX"
  channel="receiveChannel"
  auto-startup="true"
  should-delete-messages="false"
  should-mark-messages-as-read="true"
  auto-close-folder="false"
  java-mail-properties="javaMailProperties"/>

<util:properties id="javaMailProperties">
  <prop key="mail.imap.socketFactory.class">javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory</prop>
  <prop key="mail.imap.socketFactory.fallback">false</prop>
  <prop key="mail.store.protocol">imaps</prop>
  <prop key="mail.debug">false</prop>
</util:properties>
```

As I said, email body cannot be retrieved **only** when email comes without attachment. The content type is "text/html; charset=us-ascii".

If the content is "multipart/mixed", the email body content can be retrieved fine even though the BodyPart for email body has the same content type "text/html; charset=us-ascii".

Same code retrieve in all cases when email are pulled from gmail.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Please, show your `imap-idle-channel-adapter` configuration. See `setAutoCloseFolder(false)` if you are going to parse that complex message yourself.

Comment: I added the imap-idle-channel-adapter. I had configure the auto close folder as false. I don't know why the body content can be retrieved ok when the email is multipart/mixed. In this case, the BodyPart object is exactly the same content type text/html; charset=us-ascii, as when email has no attachment.

Comment: I think GMain always produces multipart messages, even if no attachments. So, how does it work when you don't close folder before producing message from that channel adapter?

Comment: Auto close folder is always False. In Code, we are not closing or open folder. The folder is always open.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I was able to retrieve the content text when email comes without attachments. The content type is  "text/html; charset=us-ascii". I tested the fix in Outlook (Exchange Server) and Gmail.
The fix is adding in the imap-idle-channel-adapter

simple-content=true

The payload will be javax.mail.Message, instead of IMAPMessage.